# Why does § enable me to remove two characters in a bash promt?

Tags: bash, terminal, text, gnome-terminator

This is a wierd and very specific problem in terminator. When i type the character "§" into a terminal window and then press backspace twice it allows me to always remove two characters, *even* if they are a part of the PS1 string .

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type "§" into terminal.
2. Erase 2 characters.
3. Repeat.

Comment: which terminal app(s)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in terminator with zsh.

Comment: What are your locale settings?

Comment: Does `stty -a` show `iutf8`? If not, try after `stty iutf8`. That should at least cover the tty device internal line editor (like when you run `cat` and enter text there). Your terminal emultor should set the `iutf8` flag when called in a UTF-8 locale. If it doesn't, that's the issue we should be investigating.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like mismatched UTF-8 settings between your terminal and the application locale.

The section sign isn't part of the ASCII character set, so it's represented as two bytes in UTF-8. Your terminal probably sends it as such, but the application side doesn't realise it's supposed to represent just one character and prints as only one. The command line editor keeps a count of how many characters you have entered, and since it thinks the section sign is two characters, it allows you to backspace that many. The terminal knows it's only one, and displays and backspaces it as one.